# How to automate/script pulling ad performance data from Facebook's Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know Facebook's Graph API has pretty heavy limits on API calls and so I'd like to have some basic principles in mind before I start developing so I'm not running a fool's errand.

Does anyone have experience automating such a task? At this point I have developed a script to pull all ads from an account and the various metrics I need for the date range I am interested in. However it is only returning results for the last month. I have run into the problem of too many API calls to Graph API in the past and would just like to know how to avoid being throttled.

Is this a known limit Facebook's Graph API has built in? Should I just query the ad performance data on a month to month basis until I get back to the date I was looking for? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: cache data, and you should not need to worry about api limits.

Comment: Do you maybe have a link to a resource that would be helpful @luschn? I'm not experienced with caching data but I will definitely look into it if it will help me out.

Comment: Have you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting already?

Comment: caching data = storing it in your database so you don´t need to call the api the whole time.